Azure OAuth Token Exchange Issue
I'm trying to exchange the code for an access token, but it comes in a strange format.
I expect a JWT token, but I get something like this:
POST - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=?
scope=User.Read
code=?
grant_type=authorization_code
client_secret=?
redirect_uri=?
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "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...


OAuth2's acces tokens are by default not JWT. Why do you expect a JWT here?


Note that, you will get such type of token when you use personal Microsoft accounts (Outlook) while logging in to get authorization code.

Initially, I ran below authorization request in browser and got this consent screen when I logged in with personal Microsoft (Outlook) account:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
client_id=appId
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope= User.Read
&state=12345


After granting the consent, I got code value in address bar like this:

When I generated the token using above code value via Postman, I got token which won't be in JWT form as below:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope: User.Read
code:code_from_above_request
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms

Response:

This is the default format of token while logging with personal Microsoft account and you cannot validate them. Instead, you can use that token to call MS Graph API based on scope permission it has:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Response:

To get tokens in JWT format, you need to sign with organizational accounts(local tenant users) that ends with .onmicrosoft.com while running authorization request.

Code:

JWT Token:

Reference:
Why my valid MS access_token can't be parsed with jwt.ms? - Stack Overflow by Carl Zhao
